# Embed a UIView in a WKWebView?

Tags: ios, uiview, ios10, wkwebview

Simple question: Is there a way to display a web page with `WKWebView` but override one part of it with a native iOS view -- ie, a subclass of `UIView`.

Comment: You can overlay a UIView on top of the WKWebView, but you can't display native UI elements inside of a WKWebView.

Comment: as alternative you can parse the web content and construct the web page with native elements, ej:UIImageView, UILabels, etc